# ACE editor installed with bower does not find my mode

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bower, amd, ace-editor

I wrote a custom mode for the [ACE editor](https://ace.c9.io)

**my-mode.js**

```
ace.define('my-mode', [/* ... */], function(require, exports, module) { /* ... */ });
```

that I try to use

**index.js**

```
var editor = ace.edit('editor');
editor.getSession().setMode('my-mode');
```

I installed the ACE editor (*ace-builds*) and *requirejs* with bower

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "dependencies": {
    "ace-builds": "^1.2.3",
    "requirejs": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

and configured *requirejs*

**requirejs-config.js**

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    ace: "bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace"
  }
});
```

My page looks like this

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <div id="editor"></div>

  <script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  <script src="requirejs-config.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js"></script>
  <script src="my-mode.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Sadly, the call

```
editor.getSession().setMode('my-mode');
```

leads to an error

```
Failed to load resource: http://localhost:5555/bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-my-mode.js
the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I configure *ace* and *requirejs* such that *my-mode* is found?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Before *my-mode* is used (for example at the beginning of *index.js*) call

```
ace.config.setModuleUrl('my-mode', '/path/to/my-mode.js');
```